# Unity: Detect which collider component of gameobject is colliding with something

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

It's a bit of a question to fit in the title. But the question is, how do i detect which collider (of a certain gameobject) is colliding with something?

Heres my example: My character (gameobject) in unity has two colliders (BoxCollider2D & CapsuleCollider2D) and the capsulecollider is my character's feet. I only want him to for example stay "grounded" if the feet (cap.collider) is colliding with something, or only be able to jump if the feet is colliding with something, and not just the BoxCollider2D (the body).
So far i use a "OnCollisionEnter2D" function to detect, and that only shows me the other object, and what it is etc. But i want to know which of my characters colliders collided, so i can specify what is going to happen when certain areas of my character is colliding.

Example on a problem: My character can touch a wall (meaning the BoxCollider2D has been hit, but not the feet) and can use the jump script, because he is "grounded" just by touching something (with box coll), which then transfers to my function "OnCollisionEnter2D" that sets the bool isGrounded to true.

Comment: [This API doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) mentions a `collider`, which is the collider that collides (what is this sentence...) with the `otherCollider`. Can't you just check what type `collider` is to see if it is a `BoxCollider2D` or a `CapsuleCollider2D` ?

Comment: I see what you're thinking, but ive been trying some alternatives etc in my function "OnCollisionEnter2D". Could you provide an example of what you mean in code in a function such as "OnCollisionEnter2D" or similar. :)

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but I would expect something along the lines of `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
      if (collision.collider is BoxCollider2D)
      {
        // Probably your character
      }
      else if (collision.collider is CapsuleCollider2D)
      {
        // Feet?
      }
    }` to work

Comment: I see what you're writing here and its right. But you're checking for the 2nd colliding object in this equation. I want to find the reference to my character. And if my character bumps into a tree, your variable "collision" would be the tree. And thats just because "OnCollisionEnter2D" only has one parameter, which is the "incoming" collisionobject onto the script (current object).

Comment: If I am not mistaking `otherCollider` is the collider of the tree in your example, if this script is at the character. `collider` on the other hand, is on the character.

Comment: I can quickly check that right now in unity. Wouldnt it be funny if i have been sitting here for 2h only to realise the parameter was my answer. :D

Comment: Im pretty sure the Collision2D col variable is the reference to the 2nd object yea. I tried this `Debug.Log("Player has collided with " + col.collider.name);`, and all it did print out was the name of everything i stepped on, so for example, the ground, a pipe etc.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. By writing this code in the "OnCollisionEnter2D" function i managed to get it working! It was the "otherCollider" variable i was needing.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
   // Debug.Log("Player has collided with " + col.collider.name);
    isGrounded = true;
    marioFalling = false;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveX * marioSpeed, 0); // Väldigt viktig, återställer hastigheten (i y) till noll, istället för att lägga till tidigare hastighet på nästa hopp.

    if (col.otherCollider is BoxCollider2D)
    {
        Debug.Log("Marios body is being tickled");
    }

    if (col.otherCollider is CapsuleCollider2D)
    {
        Debug.Log("Marios feet is being touched");
    }
}
```